# Simplify geometry of multiple features without losing shape

Tags: qgis, geometry, simplify, generalization

I am simplifying administrative boundaries using a high simplify tolerance (which is my intention so as to get a minimalist appearance).  However, after simplification, the borders of the regions no longer fit together.  What would be the most effective way to solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: In addition to the duplicate question, have a look at this site: https://boraberan.wordpress.com/2012/10/23/simplifying-multiple-neighboring-polygons/

Comment: Thanks @Fezter this is a very helpful site and the code is downloadable (.cs) . However, how would one run this C# code on a shapefile or geojson?  Am not sure what the input would be. Is it possible to run in the terminal? I am running MAC OS... any feedback would be appreciated

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really sure. I suggest asking the developer.